# Attaching data submitted by visitors to page

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

How do I append created nodes to my web page?

For example, let's say that I created a website where users could submit data to the website. I then want to take this data and add it to my page, like Reddit/4chan for example.

I have tried retrieving the data from MySQL and echoing it inside div tags using a for loop, but this does not allow me to arrange the data by, let's say, the number of upvotes.

Should I append the data using JavaScript? If one user submits data, how can I make sure all users can see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to order your data by a factor, I imagine that you added some fields like `upvotes` in your database. You just need to setup your SQL query to order this data using "ORDER BY" clause.

If you want to make it *reative* and automatic update your view with new content, you need to perform this checks using javascript (interval based ajax calls or sockets), and get your *order parameter* in your callback function to order and change the DOM with the new content.